# Write results into multiple cells using gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to work with Google Sheets via the API. I am using this [gspread documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#indices-and-tables).

Basically, I have a SQL query in a column. I pull that query into Python, run it, get the results which have the following form: `((result1), (result2) (result3) etc...)`

Simply: how do I say "paste results on B1 where each result is in it's own cell, as it should be. For instance, `(result1)` is in cell B1 and then `(result2)` is in cell B2 etc.

When I follow the documentation to update a cell, the entire set of results is written to a single cell. Do I really have to for-loop through all cells in the range and paste the corresponding value from results?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think your "shortcut" will work. Refer to [Basic Writing docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing) on how to write to sheets because you'll be using the A1 Notiation where you need to explicitly state where you're writing.  Examples are included in the given link.